# Is this function pure or impure?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I [saw this](https://james-priest.github.io/udacity-nanodegree-react/course-notes/react-redux.html) impure function on [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/react-nanodegree--nd019), but I think it's pure - I am confused. Can some one please explain?

```
const addAndPrint = (a, b) => { 
  const sum = a+b;
  console.log(`The sum is ${sum}`);
  return sum;
};
```

Comment: It depends on whether you consider logging to the console to be a side effect or not. Do you?

Comment: Basically, this is opinion-based.

Comment: I used to think this was pure, but using `console` can only ever be a side effect. So in my _opinion_, no it's not a pure function.

Comment: Sure, it doesn't alter any state within your program, but it does alter the state of the real world, your screen namely. Hence it is impure. @Cerbrus can you replace this expression with its result value without changing the behavior of the program? Purity isn't a matter of opinion.

Comment: @ftor: That's your _opinion_. "Purity" is a theory. It's a "style". It's something someone made up. I'm not saying it's right or wrong, but it's certainly open to interpretation.

Comment: @Cerberus I think it comes from math and people try to transfer it to programming. I can't tell if this is possible at all. I think every pure language has its dirty, impure secrets. I am not an expert, though.

Comment: @ftor: That I can certainly agree with.

Comment: @ftor how about this : `let add => (a, b, f) => { f('the sum is ' + (a + b)); return a + b; };`. Now purity depends on the caller (`f` could be a no-op). Or how about wrapping it in a data.Task? Is it pure then? You can go down that rabbit hole arbitrarily deeply.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'd say `add` is a HOF and pure, if `f` is pure. And `((x, y) => () => addAndPrint(x, y)) (2, 3)` is also pure, however, not the subsequent call. But I got your point, it's a matter of confidence.

Answer (score 17):

It is not a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), because

```
console.log(`The sum is ${sum}`);
```

violates point 2:

> 2. Evaluation of the result does not cause any semantically observable side effect or output, such as mutation of mutable objects or output to I/O devices

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Which part violates it?

Comment: @maxpaj "*output to I/O devices*"?

Comment: It doesn't violate, which variable can be mutated ?

Comment: @Bergi Ah, yes, the console.log. I guess that makes sense.

Comment: @marvel308 There's an "*or*" not an "*and*" in that sentence.

Answer (score 4):

For the same input it will always give you the same result. You don't have any outer references inside your function, so it depends only on the `input` parameters.

Something that can be considered as impure inside your function is that, (not related to the return value) somebody can change the `console`'s `log` function to do another thing.

For example

```js
const addAndPrint = (a, b) => { 
  const sum = a+b;
  console.log(`The sum is ${sum}`);
  return sum;
};

console.log(addAndPrint(4,5));
const log = console.log;
console.log = (t) => log('Not the same output');
console.log(addAndPrint(4,5));
```

And as @Nina answered, it violates to the second point, so based on the pure function's declaration, it is not a pure function.

Comment: No, we usually don't consider something impure just because it uses an overwritable function; function references are normally treated as constant.

Comment: @Bergi understood you. But we only consider, yes? I mean for example I can refer the function to access a global variable and change it's state

Comment: Well we always have to *consider* something to be pure, as every evaluation on an real computer involves changing memory. We do this kind of reasoning when it is useful, and to be doable we *assume* that references are constant.